# Экранирование ввода

Tags: php, mysql, экранирование

Подскажите какое экранирование сделать для полей "ФИО" "телефон" и "Описание".
На данный момент у меня следующее

```
$name = $row['name'];
        $name = strip_tags($name);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
        $name = mysqli_escape_string ($connection, $name);
        $name = addslashes($name);
```

но это выглядит слишком криво.

Тем более то формат должны быть следующие - фио- "'", телефон- " +0", описание- " '/"!@#$%^&*()_`".

И где выводить проверку в теле кода или при проверке $_POST(еще в начале сраницы)?

Заранее  спасибо.

Comment: Никакое. не вставляйте переменные непосредственно в запрос, ставьте `?` и используйте привязку переменных к запросу http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: А на допустимость в каждом конкретном поле конкретных символов можно использовать регулярные выражения. И если ожидается последующий вывод обратно в HTML текст то возможно strip_tags или htmlspecialchars для исключения XSS